# EVR shows few black frames on Window after SetPosition before play

Tags: c++, visual-c++, render, directshow

I am using GraphEdt(directShow) with graph built in [AsyncFile(mp4)]-[LAV splliter]-[LAV video decoder]-[EVR].
I pressed `pause` and the windows pops up and not enter play state yet.

And it always get few black frames on window, when I seek the bar. This makes result blinks when seeking. IIt's so weird. Replaced the render to VMR, this issue is gone, no blinks/black frames shows.

In the code, I get this situation immediately after I call IMediaControl->SetPosition().

How to configure EVR to make this issue gone?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

After I set `MFVideoRenderPrefs_DoNotRepaintOnStop` on `IMFVideoDisplayControl::SetRenderingPrefs()` call, interface queried from EVR filter, the issue is gone.

Reference:

- [Enhanced Video Renderer Filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375607)
- [`IMFVideoDisplayControl::SetRenderingPrefs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms698981)
- [`MFVideoRenderPrefs` enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms701834)